Spring Boot RestClient Multipart request working only with interceptor
I'm facing something strange. With Spring Boot 3.2.0 I'm trying to call a webservice expecting a Multipart form data.
The same code using RestClient only works when the code is intercepted through a RequestInterceptor. Only calling the execution method in the interceptor is enough to make the code work. Otherwise I get an error saying that the request is missing the "file" part.
I did not include the code of the logging part because it seems useless regarding the behaviour. But of course we could see the "file" part included in the request (otherwise it would not work with this code)
      public void send(ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource, Object otherObject) {
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .requestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()) // when commented not working
            .baseUrl("http://url.webservice.com")
            .defaultHeader("AUTH_HEADER", "AUTH_VALUE")
            .build();



        // create multipart form data
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        parts.add("file", byteArrayResource);
        parts.add("otherObject", otherObject);

        return restClient.post()
            .uri(createPostConfig.urlSuffix())
            .body(parts)
            .retrieve()
            .body(String.class);
    }


    public static class RequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }
    }


I had a similar issue that POST requests timed out when not using an interceptor. The issue was that the content-length header was not set automatically. From Spring 6.1 release notes:

To reduce memory usage in RestClient and RestTemplate, most
ClientHttpRequestFactory implementations no longer buffer request
bodies before sending them to the server. As a result, for certain
content types such as JSON, the contents size is no longer known, and
a Content-Length header is no longer set. If you would like to buffer
request bodies like before, simply wrap the ClientHttpRequestFactory
you are using in a BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory.

And this made it work for me:
JdkClientHttpRequestFactory jdkClientHttpRequestFactory = new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory();                  
jdkClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
restClient = builder
               .baseUrl(baseUrl)
               .requestFactory(
                   new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(jdkClientHttpRequestFactory))
               .build();

